# How to automatically scroll through messages in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Im trying to implement a String list of messages to display on the screen for my login page. I need these messages to be able to scrolled through if the user decides to. I am using a label for my text. If the user does not scroll, then the messages will automatically scroll through. I tried using iCarousel but it does not achieve the effect I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Libray https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel
or easily you can also make auto scrollable label your own self like

```
func startAnimation()
{
    //Animating the label automatically change as per your requirement

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {
            () -> Void in
            self.demoLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.demoLabel.bounds.size.width / 2, y: self.demoLabel.center.y)
        }, completion:  nil)
    })
}
```

**Usage**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let demoLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textColor = .green
        label.text = "This is the demo label for testing automatically scrolling of uilabel when user not clicked on label if user click on label the scrolling is stoped."
        return label
    }()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(demoLabel)
       startAnimation()
}
```